# How to get a variable to the element from a function in .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var el = $('#someElement');

el.data('f', function() {
  console.log(this); // return an object to the window
});
```

So i would like something that return me an object like "el" from inside the function.

The reason is that the element is going to be duplicated and i don't know on which element the function is applied.

Answer (score 1):

You could do (if i understand correctly, which i'm unsure)

```
var el = $('#someElement');
var clone = el.clone();
el.data('f', function() {
  console.log(clone); // return an object to the window
});
```

Comment: ok but i should surround this by `(function() {//code})();` to remember the var. No better way ?